# '-std=c++11' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C

Tags: c++, c, c++11, makefile, automake

I m trying to build json-c with the following configuration:

```
./configure --target=arm-linux-androideabi --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
            --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

but I got the following error:

```
cc1: error: command line option '-std=c++11' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [-Werror]
```

I tried to add `--disable-std-c++11` and `--disable-std-cpp11` to the configure but I got always the same problem.

How to fix that?

Comment: what are your `CFLAGS`? Do you have any predefined `CFLAGS`?

Comment: Perhaps you have some environment variables, e.g. CFLAGS that erroneously  contains -std=c++11 ?

Comment: @iharob. I just run the `./configure` and then `make`

Comment: @nos how to remove the -std=c++11 from the `CFLAGS`

Comment: try `CFLAGS="" ./configure --target=arm-linux-androideabi --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
            --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` or `unset CFLAGS` before running configure.

Comment: @iharob It does not work

Comment: What package is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is no one answered me, I will answer to myself

In fact the `-std=c++11` is injected by the global variable `CPPFLAGS`.

I just added the following line before the `./configure` and the `-std=c++11` disappear

```
export CPPFLAGS=""
```

Comment: The CPP in CPPFLAGS is for C PreProcessor, not C PlusPlus. The latter has a CXXFLAGS environment variable. If you have `-std=c++11` in your global CPPFLAGS, you're doing something very wrong, and you should not be changing any script to work around it, you should see what's setting that environment variable and get rid of it there.

Comment: @hvd I m not doing anything. I just executed `./configure` with the options indicated in the question and then executed the make and I got this problem

Comment: @hvd here after the package I m compiling: https://s3.amazonaws.com/json-c_releases/releases/json-c-0.12.tar.gz

Comment: @hvd I checked the source code and there is no `c++11`

Comment: You're the one who added `-std=c++11` to your global CPPFLAGS, aren't you? Who else could it have been, especially if you already found that the package isn't doing that?

Comment: @hvd How can I added it and I just executed `./configure` and `make` that's all. may be it comes from my linux global variables

Comment: Precisely. Those global variables are still something you configured on your system, and should be fixed there. You'll find many other packages that also won't accept language-specific flags in CPPFLAGS.

Comment: How I can fix them in my linux system. shoul I put `CPPFLAGS` in the `.profile` file ?

Comment: You shouldn't put it anywhere, but you did, somewhere. You should find where, and remove it.

Comment: @MOHAMED You, or someone else with access to your computer have placed it on your system. Somewhere, we don't know. Perhaps in ̃~/.bashrc or /etc/bashrc or /etc/profile, or any other script that initializes the shell you are using. So you should find that place, and remove the -std=c++11.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error (building a later version of `json-c`) by setting the environment variable `CPPFLAGS` to `-std=c++11` before running `./configure; make; make install`. Without that explicit setting, the problem didn't appear. Your `export CPPFLAGS=""` (or, better, `unset CPPFLAGS`) is a workaround. The underlying problem is that you have `CPPFLAGS` set in your environment. The solution is to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

If the flag was set using `ADD_DEFINITIONS(-std=c++0x)`, it can be removed using `REMOVE_DEFINITIONS(-std=c++0x)`, then set for c++ only using `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")`

Why would one do such a thing?  In large, mixed "mostly-C++" projects, `ADD_DEFINITIONS` and `REMOVE_DEFINITIONS` is a quick way to switch between `std c++` levels based on a particular cmake directory but has the unintended side effect of throwing warnings during compilation -- or worse compilation failures on `-Werror` builds.

Answer (score -1):

For me this meant "edit setup.py and remove where it adds -std=c++11" FWIW.

Comment: What is `setup.py`? There is no such file in json-c.

Comment: If you get this error when doing a python style C build (setup.py is kind of like its equivalent to configure FWIW).